# How can I configure fail2ban for use with OS X

Tags: security, homebrew, firewall, macos

I've seen [instructions for configuring fail2ban on BSD using pf](http://www.effu.se/2011/03/Integrating-PF-with-Fail2ban-0.9) but I'm not sure how these can be adapted to configure the fail2ban rules that ship with homebrew to configure Yosemite's firewall for safety.

What changes do I need to make, and to which files, to enable fail2ban safely on my OSX server?

Comment: I'd really prefer NOT to change my question. I have both Yosemite and El Capitan in my network, so both are pertinent answers.

Comment: I'll hold off on closing this for a while as too broad. We strongly prefer one question per question. Let's discuss site policy on [meta] if the close reasons don't make sense to you... Also, how far have you gotten? What error do you receive when you start the app?

Comment: @ChrisR I have already answered a similar question regarding the non-homebrew [fail2ban](http://sourceforge.net/projects/fail2ban/)  in the question [here](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/198636/blocking-incoming-hostile-traffic-dynamically-with-pf-and-fail2ban-on-os-x/198741). Please check if the answer helps. If you have problems with the answer (beyond adapting some config files and paths), please specify this in your question here.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running the macosx server product (as well as running macosx as a server), you can try [activating the adaptive firewall](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT200259) (man afctl(8)). It is a tool that watches for auth failures and blocks the originating host for a short time. Not quite as flexible as fail2ban but catches some of the services that don't log auth failures.