# How to setup the adaptive firewall

Tags: macos, server.app, firewall

I have followed this link: [Turn on the adaptive firewall in macOS Server](https://support.apple.com/pt-pt/HT200259)

and I get this output, but I don't know if I have indeed activated the adaptive firewall:

```
No ALTQ support in kernel
ALTQ related functions disabled
No ALTQ support in kernel
ALTQ related functions disabled
pf enabled
Token : 13540967312582709951
No ALTQ support in kernel
ALTQ related functions disabled
```

I want to let the adaptive firewall automatically add users with several failed attempts to login.

I have successfully added a certain IP to the firewall blacklist, but I was unable to see it at hb_summary, don't know if it is supposed to show manually added IP's there. And it was not adding automatically when I supposedly turned it on.

There was a brute force attack at my IMAPs port, and my adaptive firewall was not adding that IP in the blacklist. Only postfix was dealing with it by doing a fatal error because of too many errors and the program terminated, but it was just for a very short period of time.

Server specs:

- Server.app 3.2.2
- Mac OS X 10.9.5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After diving into the Adaptive Firewall [once more](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/179954/93229) I got the impression that the whole system is flawed and the documentation is a mess.

The command `.../hb_summary` apparently doesn't work at all because it seems to rely on the file /private/var/db/af/blockedHosts getting populated
by *ipfw* which isn't activated in 10.9 (and wouldn't work with the 400.AdaptiveFirewall anchor). *pf* doesn't use the file blockedHosts at all.

The best you can do is the following:

- Enable the Adaptive Firewall service

  ```
  sudo /Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/usr/sbin/serverctl enable service=com.apple.afctl
  ```
- Populate the whitelist with

  ```
  sudo /Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/usr/libexec/afctl -c
  ```
- Define max bad auth attempts (e.g. 3) and ban time (e.g. 60 minutes)

  ```
  sudo /Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/usr/libexec/afctl -T 3
  sudo /Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/usr/libexec/afctl -H 60
  ```

  This will modify the file /Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/private/etc/emond.d/rules/AdaptiveFirewall.plist.

  Check the mod with:

  ```
  sudo grep -m 2 -A 4 hostBlockThreshold /Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/private/etc/emond.d/rules/AdaptiveFirewall.plist
  ```
- Relaunch emond: `sudo killall emond`
- Add known bad hosts for a long time:

  ```
  sudo /Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/usr/libexec/afctl -a 104.16.35.178 -t 1000000
  ```

  (Please be aware of the [y2038 problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem)).
  This will modify the file /private/var/db/af/blacklist. Hosts added here usually don't survive a reboot.
- Start af with `sudo /Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/usr/libexec/afctl -f`
- To get blocked hosts enter:

  ```
  sudo pfctl -a com.apple/400.AdaptiveFirewall -t blockedHosts -T show -vvv
  ```

  To get pf's state enter `sudo pfctl -s all`.

This is tested with hostile `ssh` and `openssl s_client -connect imapserver_ip:993` login attempts.

---

After a reboot the `.../afctl -f` command will start pf and af but in at least one of two cases it doesn't block hostile login attempts though it's announced in the log file.

---

Improvements:

After modifying the keys *debugLevel* and *logEvents* in the file /etc/emond.d/emond.plist,:

```
    ...
    <key>debugLevel</key>
    <integer>3</integer>
    ...
    <key>logEvents</key>
    <true/>
    ...
```

creating the file /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.afctl_boot.plist with the content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Disabled</key>
    <false/>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.apple.afctl_boot</string>
    <key>Program</key>
    <string>/Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/usr/libexec/afctl</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/usr/libexec/afctl</string>
        <string>-f</string>
    </array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

and loading it with:

```
sudo launchctl load /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.afctl_boot.plist
```

it seems to work more reliably. The Adaptive Firewall will be loaded at boot time. No further afctl launch command is required!

Comment: First of all, thank you very much for the awesome tutorial! Is in indeed a mess, all the data that apple have published about setting up this firewall in previous versions of macosx.

Comment: I have made several tests, and i discover that my server doesnt allowed more then 6 attempts to login through the same username by default, but was unable to add the bad IP in the blacklist automatically till now. After i made the tutorial till the "improvement" part, i notice that now with hostBlockThreshold of 12 and hostMinBlockTime of 60, it is working fine  (i have made this test at least 2 times and both work fine).

Comment: I will do the improvement part to avoid have to exec that afctl -f every time i reboot the system.

P.S. I will change the title of this question to be more intuitive for others that may encounter this problem.

Comment: Just to let you know that in my system i had LaunchDaemons instead of yours LaunchDaemon.

How can i have access to the emond logevents? (I have already changed emond.plist as you have made in improvements)

Comment: @SipriusPT LaunchDaemon was misspelled and I corrected it!

Comment: also the daemon seems to be working fine =) with this i notice that i was having a lot of authentication failures at my postfix service, from 'good' IPs, my external IP got blacklisted has well as other user IP, i will have to see this next =)

Comment: @SipriusPT The first sentence (... flawed ... mess.) of my answer is the most important. I recommend to commit firewalling to an external device (like a dedicated firewall).