# Is macOS Mojave (and up?) doing extra network blocking compared to macOS High Sierra?

Tags: macos, network, osx-server

I have two computers on the same LAN:

- *old*: macOS High Sierra + Server.app
- *new*: macOS Mojave + Server.app

Both have the Application Firewall turned off

When I run `nc -l 8082` on one I can connect to it from the other using a telnet client, both ways. I can also connect from other Macs on the local network.

But when connected to from the outside, the High Sierra computer accepts network connections, while the Mojave computer doesn't.

In other words, I set router NAT and router firewall to accept port 8082 and route it to *old*, the old computer is available for connections. I see the traffic (NAT and fw) in the logging on the (Ubiquiti) router (I've set logging active on the NAT rule and the allow firewall rule):

```
Dec 28 03:48:21 ubntrouter kernel: [WAN_IN-40-A]IN=eth1 OUT=switch0 MAC=24:a4:3c:b3:ae:0a:02:1d:b5:ca:a9:4b:08:00 SRC=[outsideclient] DST=[old:privateip] LEN=60 TOS=0x10 PREC=0x00 TTL=55 ID=18302 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=35900 DPT=8082 WINDOW=29200 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0
Dec 28 03:48:21 ubntrouter kernel: [NAT-2-DNAT] IN=eth1 OUT= MAC=24:a4:3c:b3:ae:0a:02:1d:b5:ca:a9:4b:08:00 SRC=[outsideclient] DST=[publicip] LEN=60 TOS=0x10 PREC=0x00 TTL=56 ID=18302 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=35900 DPT=8082 WINDOW=29200 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0
```

But when I do exactly the same with the new computer, I get 'Connection refused'. I still see the same (except for private inside ip of course) traffic attempt in the logging of the router, though:

```
Dec 28 03:49:24 ubntrouter kernel: [WAN_IN-40-A]IN=eth1 OUT=switch0 MAC=24:a4:3c:b3:ae:0a:02:1d:b5:ca:a9:4b:08:00 SRC=[outsideclient] DST=[new:privateip] LEN=60 TOS=0x10 PREC=0x00 TTL=55 ID=53334 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=35946 DPT=8082 WINDOW=29200 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0
Dec 28 03:49:24 ubntrouter kernel: [NAT-2-DNAT] IN=eth1 OUT= MAC=24:a4:3c:b3:ae:0a:02:1d:b5:ca:a9:4b:08:00 SRC=[outsideclient] DST=[publicip] LEN=60 TOS=0x10 PREC=0x00 TTL=56 ID=53334 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=35946 DPT=8082 WINDOW=29200 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0
```

After many hours hunting for a mistake, checking and double-checking, I must now cautiously conclude that the difference is in High Sierra versus Mojave. Somehow, HighSierra accepts the network traffic, while Mojave blocks it. I suspect Apple security measures, accepting traffic from the local IP range but not when originating from outside that IP range.

Assuming that is the case. What could be causing this (application firewall is off) and how can I fix it so I can actually provide a service from my Mac to the outside world?

Comment: Try disabling the firewall with the command `pfctl -d` and making the connection.  Let us know what happens...

Answer (score 1):

A macOS server system provides two and half firewalls:

- Application Firewall (with a GUI > System Preferences > Security & Privacy)
- pf (only 3rd-party GUIs)
- Adaptive Firewall which is (or at least was) based on ipfw **and** pf (and thus in parts flawed because Apple botched it by removing `ipfw`). Partly fixed here: [How to setup the adaptive firewall](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/268834/93229).

Only the last one is exclusive to systems with Server.app installed and configured.

---

Launching Server.app for the first time will modify */etc/pf.conf* and add an additional pf anchor: */private/etc/pf.anchors/com.apple.server-firewall*. This anchor loads additional anchors from */Library/Server/Firewall/Anchors/*.

By default all firewalls are off and defunct and no substantial rules are defined.

As soon as you change in Server.app: **Server > hostname > Access > Default Network Access** the default setting *all networks* to something else, the linked anchors are fed with rules depending on your settings and the pf daemon is launched. Changing back to *all networks* will remove all rules related to default network access but the pf daemon continues to run.

1. *all networks* will allow NATed traffic from the Internet directed to your server
2. *private networks* will prohibit NATed traffic from the Internet directed to your server based on the propagated rules.

---

AFAIR there is no difference between the various Server v5 versions (at least El Capitan - Catalina) regarding the initial setting of **Default Network Access** which always is and was *all networks*.

Comment: Thank you. Interesting information you linked to. Without a maintained 3rd party app, it is hard to rely on ageing information about previous situations, though. Is there a decent 3rd party to manage the entire firewalling setup you know of?

Comment: @gctwnl There is no 3rd-party app managing all three I know of. I have to test whether the Adaptive Firewall works in the meantime - which would be a separate question...

Comment: I've found Murus, which manages pf and which looks interesting and is still supported (beta for Catalina available)

Comment: @gctwnl Murus (Lite|Basic|Pro) doesn't manage macOS' pf anchors. You can either keep the system's pf.conf untouched & unmanaged or overwrite them. Then you have to do the Server.app's config yourself.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in the Server.app. This app may lock down network traffic in some way (how is unknown to me, I'd be interested to learn).

The Server.app in Mojave has the server itself as its first entry on the left, select that, then select the 'Access' tab. There, 'Default Network Access' was set to 'private networks' on Mojave and 'all networks' on High Sierra, with on High Sierra the services per-service locked down unless they had to be available from the outside.

Probably best to use 'private networks' only and have custom entries for the ports that need to be accessible from the outside.